# Removing characters from column in pandas data frame

Tags: json, pandas, twitter

My goal is to (1) import Twitter JSON, (2) extract data of interest, (3) create pandas data frame for the variables of interest. Here is my code:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

tweets = []
for line in open('00.json'):
    try:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        tweets.append(tweet)
    except:
        continue

# Tweets often have missing data, therefore use -if- when extracting "keys"

tweet = tweets[0]

ids = [tweet['id_str'] for tweet in tweets if 'id_str' in tweet] 
text = [tweet['text'] for tweet in tweets if 'text' in tweet]
lang = [tweet['lang'] for tweet in tweets if 'lang' in tweet]
geo = [tweet['geo'] for tweet in tweets if 'geo' in tweet]
place = [tweet['place'] for tweet in tweets if 'place' in tweet]

# Create a data frame (using pd.Index may be "incorrect", but I am a noob)
df=pd.DataFrame({'Ids':pd.Index(ids),
               'Text':pd.Index(text),
               'Lang':pd.Index(lang),
               'Geo':pd.Index(geo),
               'Place':pd.Index(place)})

# Create a data frame satisfying conditions:
df2 = df[(df['Lang']==('en')) & (df['Geo'].dropna())]
```

So far, everything seems to be working fine.

Now, the extracted values for Geo result in the following example:

```
df2.loc[1921,'Geo']
{'coordinates': [39.11890951, -84.48903638], 'type': 'Point'}
```

To get rid of everything except the coordinates inside the squared brackets I tried using:

```
df2.Geo.str.replace("[({':]", "") ### results in NaN
# and also this:
df2['Geo'] = df2['Geo'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('{'coordinates': [').rstrip('], 'type': 'Point'')) ### results in syntax error
```

Please advise on the correct way to obtain coordinates values only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line from your question indicates that this is an issue with understanding the underlying data type of the returned object.

```
df2.loc[1921,'Geo']
{'coordinates': [39.11890951, -84.48903638], 'type': 'Point'}
```

You are returning a Python dictionary here -- not a string! If you want to return just the values of the coordinates, you should just use the `'coordinates'` key to return those values, e.g.

```
df2.loc[1921,'Geo']['coordinates']
[39.11890951, -84.48903638]
```

The returned object in this case will be a Python list object containing the two coordinate values. If you want just one of the values, you can slice the list, e.g.

```
df2.loc[1921,'Geo']['coordinates'][0]
39.11890951
```

This workflow is much easier to deal with than casting the dictionary to a string, parsing the string, and recapturing the coordinate values as you are trying to do.

So let's say you want to create a new column called "geo_coord0" which contains all of the coordinates in the first position (as shown above). You could use a something like the following:

```
df2["geo_coord0"] = [x['coordinates'][0] for x in df2['Geo']]
```

This uses a Python list comprehension to iterate over all entries in the `df2['Geo']` column and for each entry it uses the same syntax we used above to return the first coordinate value. It then assigns these values to a new column in `df2`.

See the [Python documentation on data structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) for more details on the data structures discussed above.

Comment: Brian, thank you for the explanation provided. Indeed, I messed up with the issue you highlighted. With your code suggestion, the problem is solved for now. Yet I'll surely dig the documentation on data structures to learn about it.

Comment: @kiton Glad I could help! Please consider [accepting my answer as a solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you feel this resolves this question.